# How to force usage TLS instead of SSL in .Net

Tags: .net, web-services, ssl

How can I force my .Net application to establish connection with some Java Web Service using TLS instead of SSL ?
Proxy to Web Service is generated as standard Web Reference (not WCF). 
Web Service url is https://........ .

Some details: 
From my .Net 4.0 application I'm invoking Java Web Service hosted on JBoss & Redhat.
This web service works properly in 50% runs, when error occurs exception message is 
'*An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host*'.

When I looked at network communication with WireShark:

- all error connections are established with SSL 'Hello Client' and being reset.
- Success connections are established with TLSv1 'Hello Client'

so forcing .Net to use TLS could resolve this strange issue.

Comment: After a long time the provider company of Java Web Service admitted thah error was on their side, they were killing connections on Firewall level. 
It was some part of theirs mis-functioning anti-DDOS protection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The place to start would be [`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol.aspx). This allows one of the [`SecurityProtocolType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.securityprotocoltype.aspx) values to be set: `Ssl3` or `Tls`, the later is documented:

> Specifies the Transport Layer Security (TLS) 1.0 security protocol.
>
> TLS assumes that a connection-oriented protocol, typically TCP, is in use. The TLS protocol is defined in IETF RFC 2246.